# change font style of script in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, scripts

I hope you are doing well. I am writing to ask you how I can change the font style of the script in math mode in latex. Actually i use \text{} to write script in equation area nicely, for example : X_{\text{ref}}. I want to know if there is a way that latex use text font style for script in math mode without using \text{}.

Comment: First of `\text` is the wrong command to use here, it does not do what you think. Use `\textup` or ` \textnormal`

Comment: You can use `\mathrm`. @daleif can you explain why `\text` should not be used.

Comment: @StefanH that depends on what you are going to write. Here I'm assuming a textual index, which (1) always have to be upright, (2) can be anything, for example in Danish the word for Lake is "sø" and "ø" is not allowed in math mode, thus the textX commands are better. Why not `\text`? Go back to (1) and try `\textit{text $X_{\text{ref}} $} ` now ref is italic as `\text` follows the surrounding text. Misusing `\text ` is nowadays the most common error I see in manuscripts, it has far passed inproper use of ``\\`` in the text.